# C# What is the best practice approach for dealing with a missing configuration file?

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I understand this may be interpreted as a subjective question, but I am unable to find anything in the documentation as to the appropriate fall back solution to an app config file either not being found, or unable to read/write due to corruption.

For the majority of my appSetting keys, I can provide default values, however for quite a few of them the application simply won't work without access to a configuration file.

A few suggestions on SO that I have seen are:

- Use default values for everything (not really an option for quite a few of my keys)
- Use custom exception handling (although a good idea for various situations, this will not help my application retrieve those required values)
- Use a back-up configuration file located in the app dir to be integrated in the event of a configuration file failure

The last suggestion appears to be the best so far, but as this application will be used 24 hours a day, 7 days a week, I don't want to have to get a user to check the configuration and confirm everything is ok (as this application will be used in a fairly critical and fast paced office, so users won't want to have to do that).

So basically, is there a hard and fast rule as to how we should handle a missing / corrupt appConfig file?

I appreciate any suggestions

Comment: With a corrupt app.config you will have hard time to just start the application, let alone 'handling' it.

Comment: I would suggest the "fail fast" approach. If your app.config is corrupt you dont want to recover and you dont really want the application to start. Best for it to fail ASAP so you can fix the corruption as if your app.config (or its data) is getting corrupt, what else could be wrong?

Comment: if someone(-thing) can corrupt your app.config, then your problem is not "where can I get valid app.config". +1 to fail fast.

Comment: A good approach would be to use a database as central storage for your configurations, then you could load it on app-start. Use the local config only as fall back if there is no internet. On that way you can configure all your clients from serverside.

Comment: Just make sure it's obvious that there's a configuration error, ideally while giving enough information to solve the problem (e.g. line number, actual setting etc.). Defaults can be very dangerous, especially if you don't specifically design them to be the safest possible option.

Comment: The configuration doesn't have to remain in the config file... you could call upon a database, another file. Obviously this is in the event that you can't find source 1, it does defer the problem of corruption

Comment: Some very good suggestions. This application will be served locally within a restricted network, so internet is out of the question due to sensitive data. I am currently using the fail fast approach, but I've read that the fail fast shouldn't be used in production as it's a sign of ill-written code. I hadn't considered the database option, seems like a very logical step to prevent local file issues.

Comment: Something I have done in the past is to embed a default config file into the application, and then restore from this if the config file on the file system disappears or is corrupt.  This might not work in your case from what you said, but might help others looking for a similar solution later.  Personally, I think the DB approach from Tim is the best idea.